# How to add multiple custom widget areas

Tags: theme-development, widgets, register-sidebar

I'm looking to add multiple widget areas to a page in my theme as id like to have widgets within certain pages. I can add one using this code, I'm just struggling with a second.

```
function new_sidebar_widget_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'new-sidebar',
    'id' => 'new-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="new-sidebar">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'new_sidebar_widget_init' );
```

Then to place it in on my page:

```
<?php  dynamic_sidebar( 'new-sidebar' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to register multiple areas:

```
function new_sidebar_widget_init() {
   register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'new-sidebar',
        'id' => 'new-sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="new-sidebar">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'new-sidebar-1',
        'id' => 'new-sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="new-sidebar">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'new_sidebar_widget_init' );
```

And then you can use them based on their ID:

```
<?php  dynamic_sidebar( 'new-sidebar' ); ?> 

<?php  dynamic_sidebar( 'new-sidebar-1' ); ?>
```